# `white-space: nowrap` affects width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table for the file uploader. File names might be long, so only the part of the name is displayed with the help of:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Everything works fine for small names (the table is inside the Bootstraps panel borders), but for the big ones I have this:
[image: With white-space: nowrap]

All the `<td>` tags have proportions with the help of `col-xs-*`, total sum of the `*` values is 12. If I comment the `white-space: nowrap;` the page looks like:
[image: With white-space:wrap commented out]

I have already checked the box sizes, only the width of the `<td>` is affected, there are no padding or margin changes.

Why is that, and how can I fix it elegantly? Thank you in advance.

```css
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead > tr> th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: none;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.file-name {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1'>
<div class='panel panel-default'>
  <div class='panel-heading'>
    <span class='help-block'><span translate>Upload files by dragging &amp; dropping or selecting them.</span>&nbsp;<a>Browse to select</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-fixed">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='f in files'>
        <td class='col-xs-6 file-name'>Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name </td>
        <td class='col-xs-5'>
          <div class='progress'>
            <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:50%'></div>
            <span class="percents">50%</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class='col-xs-1'>
          <a href>X</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you expect? if you prevent line breaks and contents are wide enough, they will overflow

Comment: @Oriol That's why I specify `overflow: hidden`. The expected behaviour is: use the `col-xs-6` width, no more, don't break the table. Unfortunately the table becomes wider.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because with the [automatic table layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout),

> the formatted content may span any number of lines but may not
>   overflow the cell box.

So you can solve this by using the fixed table layout instead. Add the following style to the table box:

```css
table-layout: fixed;
```

The problem is that your table layout is all messed up, with `display: block` and `float: left` styles. So your `table-cell`s are wrapped inside an anonymous table, which you can't select.

Either don't mess the table, or add a `display: table` wrapper.

```css
.table-fixed tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```css
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.table-fixed tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
/*.table-fixed tr,*/
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead > tr> th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: none;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.file-name {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='panel panel-default'>
  <div class='panel-heading'>
    <input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='Abort'></input>
    <span class='help-block'><span translate>Upload files by dragging &amp; dropping or selecting them.</span>&nbsp;<a>Browse to select</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-fixed">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='f in files'>
        <td class='col-xs-6 file-name'>Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name Long name </td>
        <td class='col-xs-5'>
          <div class='progress'>
            <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:50%'></div>
            <span class="percents">50%</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class='col-xs-1'>
          <a href>
            <fa name="trash" alt="delete" style="color: #FF4136"></fa>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thought about semantics, but wasn't able to find the roots. Solved the problem for me, thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem and table-layout:fixed solved it thanks .

Comment: Wow, I didn't think I would find the answer, but this is it! I also have my table (thead and tbody actually) set to `display: block` (for the purposes of making tbody only overflow-y: scroll and fixed height), which in combination with `td {white-space: nowrap;}`, causes td to ignore its CSS width property. Hacking the `display: table` back in via the tr element makes the "nowrap" td adhere to its width again, and I add `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` to make it look good. Woohoo!

Comment: Magic Trick. Thankyou

Comment: Nice! For bootstrap-vue grid, it works as well. With this tip, the grid system is fixed and now it's possible to use white-space:nowrap(or truncate-text class) for truncating text.

Answer (score -1):

You Must pass the width for the td

```
.file-name {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
 width:300px
}
```

Comment: That would make the width fixed, and I try to use `col-xs-*` so it could change depending on the page width.